# Performing T-sql like while loop in Proc sql sas

Tags: sas

I have metrics sas table like below

```
work.met_table
Metrics_Id   Metrics_desc
     1       Count_Column
     2       Sum_Column
     3       Eliminate_column
```

I wanna do something like doing while loop in T-sql

```
select count(*) :cnt_tbl from work.met_table

%let init_cnt = 1

while (&init_cnt = &cnt_tbl)
begin
   select Metrics_desc into :met_nm
   from work.met_table
   where metrics_id = 1

    Insert into some_sas_table
    Select * from another table where Metrics_desc =&met_nm
       /* Here I wanna loop all values in metrics table one by one */
end
%put &init_cnt = &int_cnt+1;
```

How this can be done in proc sql? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want as output?  Why not just join `another table` directly with `met_table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically generate code then use the SAS macro language.

But for your example there is no need to dynamically generate code.

```
proc sql ;
insert into some_sas_table
  select * 
  from another_table 
  where Metrics_desc in (select Metrics_desc from work.met_table)
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do an explicit pass through. Send your native t-sql code to run on the database Server through SAS rather than bringing the data to the SAS application server to query it.

The example below is explained in details [here](https://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/SA/MWSUG-2014-SA03.pdf).

```
PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO ODBC(DATASRC=SQLdb USER=&SYSUSERID) ;
/* Explicit PASSTHRU with SELECT */
SELECT *
FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC (
 SELECT b.idnum o.[SSdatecol] AS mydate
 FROM dbo.big_SS_table1 b
 LEFT JOIN dbo.other_SStable o
 ON b.idnum = o.memberid
 WHERE o.otherdatecol >= '2014-10-06'
 --This is a T-SQL comment that works inside SQL Server
 ) ;
;
DISCONNECT FROM ODBC ;
QUIT;
```